# Make ngx-perfect-scrollbar visible by default

Tags: angular, angular-material, perfect-scrollbar

I am using ngx-perfect-scrollbar on div element like this:

```
<div [perfectScrollbar]="config" [ngStyle]="{ 'max-height': '60vh', position: 'relative' }">
.
.
.
.
</div>
```

But the scrollbar is visible only when I hover mouse over the div element of scrollbar.
How do I make this visible all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfect scrollbar is hidden by opacity.

You can give perfect scrollbar already declared class:

```
ps-show-always
```

Which adds this:

```
perfect-scrollbar.ps-show-always > .ps.ps--active-y > .ps__rail-y,
perfect-scrollbar.ps-show-always > .ps.ps--active-x > .ps__rail-x {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed problem by adding the following styles to my global styles.scss

```
.ps > .ps__rail-x,
.ps > .ps__rail-y {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

These styles are applied on perfect-scrollbar, as ngx-perfect-scrollbar is using perfect-scrollbar behind the scene.